Case Assignment rule emails come from Org-wide default no-reply address - but only for some users
Recently, my business user reported that Experience Cloud-initiated Case Assignment rules were sending emails with a from address of the default no-reply Org Wide Email address - but not all users.
Example



User
From address
To address
Correct?




joe@foo.com
no-reply@mycompany.com
support@mycompany.com
❌


jill@bar.com
jill@bar.com
support@mycompany.com
✅



We had maybe a dozen users who were ❌ and another two dozen who were ✅.

I verified that the same Case assignment rule was executed for all users.
Normal case email from the Experience Cloud users came from their user email address, never from the default no-reply email.

Why would some users successfully have their from address attributed to themselves and others have the from address be the default no-reply email address?  And why only on Assignment rules?

The reason for this was a change released in Winter 24 - Verify Email Addresses to Send Email Through Salesforce

Salesforce requires that users have a verified email address to continue sending emails through Salesforce, such as sends to contacts or leads. Most users verify their email address as part of the sign-up process. However, some users continue to use email addresses that were added to Salesforce before the current verification process was established. If a user sends an email from an unverified email address, Salesforce rejects this email message and doesn’t complete the send. Unverified email addresses can’t be used for sends until the user verifies their email address or resets their password.

Now the doc might not be exactly correct in that the email is sent (not rejected), but the from address is coerced to the default no-reply org wide email. (as of Spring 24)

Our assignment rules were executed as part of dmlOptions on Case DML Insert.

Resolution
I created a list view of the Experience users and displayed the column User Verified Email and sure enough, the ❌ users in the OP all had unverified emails whereas the ✅ all had verified emails.
These being Experience Cloud users, I opted to use the Async Email Verification approach and wrote a script to coerce the email verification link using this Apex method:
UserManagement.sendAsyncEmailConfirmation(userId, emailTemplateId, networkId, startUrl)

